# Ubuntu Server: MySQL setup hostname to respond to domainname?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Can someone help me out how to setup my MySQL to respond to domain name or IP Address so It can be accessed outside?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special setting required to make a mysql server listen to a network socket. There only is a setting to *suppress* that default behaviour you might want to check. It is found in the main server configuration, usually `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
# Remove leading # if you don't want to listen on network (only socket - safer)
# skip-networking
```

In addition you obviously have to open the network port in your firewall to be able to access from outside. Usually that is port 3306.